# How can I get the distinct month and years in the form ModelMultipleChoiceField in django?

Tags: django, datetime, modelform

I have two models as below:

```
class Program(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    teacher = CharField(...)

class ProgramIntake(Model):
    program = ForeignKey(Program, ...)
    intake = DateField(null=True, blank=True, )
```

I have a few object for programs such as math and art
as instances of Program model:

```
math = Program.objects.create(name='math', teacher='teacher1')
art = Program.objects.create(name='art', teacher='teacher2')
```

each program has a few intakes:

```
math_intake1 = PorgramIntake.objects.create(program=math, intake='2019-01-01')
math_intake2 = PorgramIntake.objects.create(program=math, intake='2019-01-15')
math_intake3 = PorgramIntake.objects.create(program=math, intake='2020-01-01')
art_intake1 = PorgramIntake.objects.create(program=art, intake='2019-01-01')
art_intake2 = PorgramIntake.objects.create(program=art, intake='2019-02-18')
art_intake3 = PorgramIntake.objects.create(program=art, intake='2020-05-21')
```

in order to build my form I have built this model:

```
class ProgramIntakeEnroll(Model):
    available_intakes = ManyToManyField(ProgramIntake, 
    blank=True, ...)
```

and the below form usign ModelForm:

```
class ProgramIntakeEnrollForm(ModelForm):
    available_intakes = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ProgramIntakeEnroll.objects.values_list('intake', flat=True).distinct().order_by('intake'), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProgramIntakeEnroll
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have rendered this form in view as below:

```
def programs(request):
    template_name = 'programs/programs.html'
    context = {}

    if request.POST:
        program_intake_enroll_form = ProgramIntakeEnrollForm(request.POST)
        if study_intake_form.is_valid():
            pass

    else:
        program_intake_enroll_form = ProgramIntakeEnrollForm()

    context.update({'program_intake_enroll_form': program_intake_enroll_form,})
 return render(request, template_name, context)
```

and in html I have:

```
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    {{ program_intake_enroll_form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Filter</button>
</form>
```

What I expect is that I want to see the below choices only in my form:

Jan 2019

Feb 2019

Jan 2020

May 2020

I guess I have to change the queryset in my ModelForm but I do not know how to change it.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Why do you need month, year pairs? It seems like your model design doesn't represent your business logic well enough. You could create another model, which would contain these year, month pairs.

Comment: You are right. I now will post my new models as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the models as below and it is now working:

```
class IntakeRound(Model):
    intake_year = PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    intake_month = PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('intake_year', 'intake_month',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.intake_year) + '-' + str(self.intake_month)


class Program(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    intake = ManyToManyField(IntakeRound, through='ProgramIntake', blank=True)


class ProgramIntake(Model):
    program = ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='program_intakes')
    program_intake_round = ForeignKey(IntakeRound, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name='program_intakes')
    program_start_date = DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Program Start Date')
    program_submission_deadline = DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Program Submission Deadline')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('program_start_date',)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.program) + '-' + str(self.program_intake_round)
```

in order to be able to use ModelForm, and in order to separate the programs available in the database and the interest of the students, called Profile in here, I also have this model in here. Note that I do not want to populate it. At this stage, I have just built it to make a ModelForm from it:

```
class ProfileStudyInterest(Model):
    intake_rounds_of_interest = ManyToManyField(IntakeRound, blank=True, verbose_name='Intake Rounds')
```

and this is my form:

```
class ProfileInterestFilterForm(ModelForm):
    intake_rounds_of_interest = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=IntakeRound.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileStudyInterest
        fields = '__all__'
```

However, I am uncomfortable that I have  program_start_date in my model and program_intake_round at the same time in the same mode that is just the month and year of the start_date. I think this is not right or best practice from the data base design point of view